# Edit, Delete, Add items to data grid readily

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a data grid in my WPF application window, which I have to bind to an observable collection. I have to give the option to the user to be able to the edit, remove, add and edit items in this data grid.

I did the binding of the datagrid in the following, but wanted to ask how do I allow the user to add, edit/update, delete the items from the data grid readily.

Here's my current code:

**.xaml**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrQuestions" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="272" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,73,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="669" ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionsList}">
      <DataGrid.Columns>                
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstQues" Binding="{Binding Question}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="SecondQues" Binding="{Binding Answer}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ThirdQues" Binding="{Binding Hint}"/>
      </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**.xaml.cs code**

```
using Quest; //class having the format of the question

public class Master
{

    private ObservableCollection<Quest> questList;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;        

        public ObservableCollection<Quest> QuestionList
        {
            get { return questList; }
            set 
            {             
                questList = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("QuestionsList"));
            }
        }

    //Add, Edit, Remove, Reset methods required
}
```

**.cs code** (only properties mentioned here) for the class for which objects are created:

```
public string Question
        {
            get { return _question; }
            set{ _question = value; OnPropertyChanged("Question"); }
        }

        public string Answer
        {   get { return _answer; }
            set {_answer = value; OnPropertyChanged("Answer"); }
        }

        public string Hint
        {
            get { return _hint; }
            set { _hint = value; OnPropertyChanged("Hint"); }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add/delete, make sure the CanUserAddRows and CanUserDeleteRows properties are set to true. The user should then be able to add rows by entering into the blank row at the bottom and delete rows by selecting them and pressing Delete on the keyboard.

To edit rows, the IsReadOnly property must be false (which it is by default).